# marker leaflet doesnot render in react component _ React leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

this is my leaflet map component . I want to get reach cordinates when user clicks on map . I can get my cordinates correctly but I need to marker render on the map too.

```
<Map
        center={[35.4090, 51.1555]}
        zoom={18}
        maxZoom={20}
        attributionControl={true}
        zoomControl={true}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        doubleClickZoom={false}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        dragging={true}
        animate={true}
        easeLinearity={0.35}
    >

        <Marker position={this.state.points === '' ? this.state.points : [35.4090, 51.1555]} icon={pointerIcon} key={this.state.points}>
            <Popup position={this.state.points}>
                Popup for any custom information.
                </Popup>
        </Marker>

    </Map>

 handleClick = (e) => {
        const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;
        this.setState({points: [lat,lng]})
    }
```

and this is custom Icon.

```
import marker from '../../css/mapMarker.png'
import L from 'leaflet'

export const pointerIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: {marker},
    iconRetinaUrl: {marker},
    iconAnchor: [5, 55],
    popupAnchor: [10, -44],
    iconSize: [25, 55],
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [20, 92],
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided example  [`iconUrl`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#icon-iconurl)  and [`iconRetinaUrl`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#icon-iconretinaurl) properties are passed as an *object values*:

```
export const pointerIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: {marker},  
    iconRetinaUrl: {marker},
    //..
})
```

while for `L.icon` they are expected to be provided as a `String` values, that's most likely the reason why marker could not be displayed

So, either modify the example to initialize property as string data:

```
export const pointerIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: marker,  
    iconRetinaUrl: marker,
    //..
})
```

or specify Url as a property value, for example:

```
export const pointerIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/red-pushpin.png",  
    //..
})
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-px1pjs)